# Replace hostname with variable on both php backend and angularjs frontend

Tags: php, angularjs

In my web app, both the php backend and the angularjs frontend has lots of references to their hostname ("https://mydomain.xyz").

It looks really repetitive, and I would like to replace it with a variable.

Is there a variable for the hostname that I could use all through my code both on the front end on the on the back end?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use base URL tag as a place holder for your site.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-specify-the-base-url-for-all-relative-urls-in-a-document-using-html5/

Comment: @ThomsonMixab And what do I use in the php backend?

Comment: tmighty, I do not know php.  You will need to figure how create singleton global static scope base URL variable in php.